# Android - Regular repetition problem in custom listview in getView

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm pulling data into Custom Listview from the mysql database, but as follows, I have a custom button. The button is either black or red, according to the records in the database. For example, there are 30 yields in my database and I pull the data with only 2 red and 28 black. Let's say the data in red is my data number 3 and data number 5. When I start to scroll down; my data number 3 and 5 turn red, then 8 data then the yield number 13 and 15, 23 and 25 turns red .. so there is a repetition .. I can't prevent it .. Is there a solution to this? Can you give support with sample code? My Custom Adapter code is as follows:

```
public class CostumAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<Ses> {
        private ArrayList<Ses> list;
        private ViewHolderr vHolder;
        boolean flag = false;

        public CostumAdaptor(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Ses> list) {
            super(context, resource, list);
            list = new ArrayList<Ses>();
            list.addAll(list);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        public Ses getItem(int position) {
            return list.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return list.get(position).hashCode();
        }

        public View getView(int position, View conView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View vi = conView;

            if (vi == null) {

                vHolder = new ViewHolderr();
                vi = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.tiyatro_item, null);

                vHolder.tiyatro_adi = vi.findViewById(R.id.tiyatro_adi);
                vHolder.begeni_sayisi2 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.begeni_sayisi2);
                vHolder.daha_sonra_dinleyecegim_2 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.daha_sonra_dinleyecegim_2);
                vHolder.begenmedim_2 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.begenmedim_2);
                vHolder.tiyatro = vi.findViewById(R.id.tiyatro);
                vHolder.tur = vi.findViewById(R.id.tur);
                vHolder.mensei = vi.findViewById(R.id.mensei);
                vHolder.yapimci = vi.findViewById(R.id.yapimci);
                vHolder.songCoverImage = vi.findViewById(R.id.coverImage);
                vHolder.begendim = vi.findViewById(R.id.begendim);
                vHolder.begenmedim = vi.findViewById(R.id.begenmedim);
                vHolder.daha_sonra_dinleyecegim = vi.findViewById(R.id.daha_sonra_dinleyecegim);
                vi.setTag(vHolder);
            }
            else {
                vHolder = (ViewHolderr) vi.getTag();
            }

            Ses dmodel = (Ses) list.get(position);

            String t_tiyatro_adi = dmodel.getTiyatro_adi();
        
            vHolder.tiyatro_adi.setTag(dmodel);
            vHolder.tiyatro.setTag(dmodel);
            vHolder.tur.setTag(dmodel);
            vHolder.mensei.setTag(dmodel);
            vHolder.yapimci.setTag(dmodel);
            vHolder.begendim.setTag(dmodel);
            vHolder.tiyatro_adi.setText(dmodel.getTiyatro_adi());
            vHolder.tiyatro.setText(dmodel.getTiyatro());
            vHolder.tur.setText(dmodel.getTur());
            vHolder.mensei.setText(dmodel.getMensei());
            vHolder.yapimci.setText(dmodel.getYapimci());

            String CACHE = t_tiyatro_adi;
        
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                   for (int i = 0; i < List1.size(); i++) {

                        for (int ii = 0; ii < List2.size(); ii++) {

                            if (List1.get(i).equals(List2.get(ii))) {

                                if (List1.get(i).equals(CACHE)) {
                                    flag = true;
                                    vHolder.begendim.setImageResource(R.drawable.begendim_dolu);
                                    
                                }

                            }

                        }

                    }

                    if (!flag) {
                        vHolder.begendim.setImageResource(R.drawable.begendim_bos);
                    }
                    
                }

            }, 250);

            return vi;
        }

        private class ViewHolderr {
            TextView tiyatro_adi, tiyatro, tur, mensei, yapimci, begeni_sayisi2, daha_sonra_dinleyecegim_2, begenmedim_2;
            ImageView songCoverImage;
            ImageView begendim;
        }

    }
```

Note: List1 and List2 are ArrayLists pulled from the mysql database and compared with a for loop. The color of the button is red or black as a result of the comparison.

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: I solved my problem with RecyclerView.